# Is there a better GroupBy to Dictionary (or solution) to bucketting?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Is there a way to write the ToDictionary statement below using the SQL-ish Linq syntax?

```
public class KeyedType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<string,List<KeyedType>> groups =
    list.GroupBy((g) => g.Name)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you find yourself with a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TSomething>>`, you may find you can happily use a [`Lookup<TKey, TSomething>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx). If this proves to be the case, you can use [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353368.aspx) to make one.

However, neither for [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353368.aspx) nor for your code is there a query expression syntax available, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow by doing the `GroupBy` you already bucked. Try to convert to a Dictionary in case is really necessary. E.g. using group by:

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(g => g.Name);
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    var groupName = group.Key;
    var valueList = group.Select(obj => obj.Value);
    foreach (var value in valueList)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```